# EditorTemplate for DataType.Time won't be applied

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I have a from where i want to have a editor for a start- and end-time.

So i created a **EditorTemplate** in path 'Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Time.cshtml'.

```cs
@model string
 @{
  var htmlAttributes = this.GetControlHtmlAttributes();
        htmlAttributes.AddClass("time");
        htmlAttributes.AddAttribute("style", "background-color: fuchsia");
    }
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, htmlAttributes: htmlAttributes)
```

In my view, i call

```
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].kal_von)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].kal_bis)
</td>
```

(just note: it does not work if i call it like this:

```
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].kal_bis, "Time")
</td>
```

)

and the model looks like this:

```
[StringLength(5)][DataType(DataType.Time)][DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
[DisplayNameAttribute("d_kal_termin.kal_von")]
public string kal_von { get; set; }

[StringLength(5)][DataType(DataType.Time)][DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
[DisplayNameAttribute("d_kal_termin.kal_bis")]
public string kal_bis { get; set; }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have something like this in your code? Where you replace the default RazorViewEngine?

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AppRazorViewEngine());
```

If so, make sure your custom ViewEngine contains the path to your EditorTemplates directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add UIHint to your model

```
[StringLength(5)]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
[UIHint("Time")]
[DisplayNameAttribute("d_kal_termin.kal_von")]
public string kal_von { get; set; }

[StringLength(5)]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
[UIHint("Time")]
[DisplayNameAttribute("d_kal_termin.kal_bis")]
public string kal_bis { get; set; }
```